# What technique should I use to extract this data?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm trying to populate this data to build hourly output divided by product type. Basicly on each line 3 types of product can run. And it can be change as of often as 4 times per hour but sometimes one product is running whole day.

```
Line  Product  Hour  ProductStopped           TimeStamp                HourCount
1     A        7     2014-01-28 07:56:30.000  2014-01-28 07:52:47.000  222
1     A        7     2014-01-28 07:56:30.000  2014-01-28 07:53:52.000  225
1     A        7     2014-01-28 07:56:30.000  2014-01-28 07:54:57.000  297
1     B        7     2014-01-28 08:05:20.000  2014-01-28 07:54:57.000  297
1     A        7     2014-01-28 07:56:30.000  2014-01-28 07:55:59.000  321
1     B        7     2014-01-28 08:05:20.000  2014-01-28 07:55:59.000  321
1     B        7     2014-01-28 08:05:20.000  2014-01-28 07:57:02.000  332
1     B        7     2014-01-28 08:05:20.000  2014-01-28 07:58:08.000  364
1     B        7     2014-01-28 08:05:20.000  2014-01-28 07:59:14.000  420
1     B        8     2014-01-28 08:05:20.000  2014-01-28 08:00:16.000  456
1     B        8     2014-01-28 08:05:20.000  2014-01-28 08:01:19.000  489
1     B        8     2014-01-28 08:05:20.000  2014-01-28 08:02:22.000  523
1     B        8     2014-01-28 08:05:20.000  2014-01-28 08:03:25.000  589
1     A        8     NULL                     2014-01-28 08:03:25.000  589
1     B        8     2014-01-28 08:05:20.000  2014-01-28 08:04:30.000  634
1     A        8     NULL                     2014-01-28 08:04:30.000  634
1     B        8     2014-01-28 08:05:20.000  2014-01-28 08:05:35.000  678
1     A        8     NULL                     2014-01-28 08:05:35.000  678
1     A        8     NULL                     2014-01-28 08:06:39.000  720
1     A        8     NULL                     2014-01-28 08:07:45.000  745
```

HourCount is a number of parts produced from shift start (7am) and will be counted to the end of shift (7pm). If product change from A to B, HourCount still carry on as it is not related to product but a machine. I would like to find out how much of each product Is made in hour.
I would like this table to look like that:

```
Line   Product   Hour   Quantity
1      A         7      321
1      B         7      78
1      C         7      0          (or without this row if is 0 for the product)
1      A         8      56
1      B         8      346
........
2      A         7      533
2      B         7      43
....
```

I have added new column ProductStopped, where date and time is recorded when product was stopped to outputting, Unfortunetly I'm not able to add when have started as this would resolve all my issues:) 
 I have slightly modified @OGHaza solution with gives me almost right values, the problem I'm having now is when ProductStopped is NULL ( still running).

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT t1.*
  ,CASE WHEN t1.Stop >
        (SELECT top 1 Stop
         FROM t t2
         WHERE t1.TimeStamp = t2.TimeStamp
           AND t1.LineID = t2.LineID
           AND t1.Hour = t2.Hour 
           AND t1.Product <> t2.Product
           AND t1.HourCount = t2.HourCount
         ORDER BY TimeStamp
         )
         OR t1.Stop IS NULL
    THEN 0
    ELSE 1
   END AS InProduction
FROM t t1
)

SELECT LineID
    ,Product
    ,Hour
    ,SUM(CASE WHEN PrevInProduction = 1 
          THEN HourCount - PrevCount
          ELSE 0
     END) AS Units
FROM (SELECT t1.*
        ,(SELECT top 1 InProduction
          FROM cte t2
          WHERE t2.TimeStamp < t1.TimeStamp
            AND t1.Product = t2.Product
            AND t1.LineID = t2.LineID
          ORDER BY TimeStamp DESC
         ) AS PrevInProduction
        ,(SELECT top 1 HourCount
          FROM cte t2
          WHERE t2.TimeStamp < t1.TimeStamp
            AND t1.Product = t2.Product
            AND t1.LineID = t2.LineID
          ORDER BY TimeStamp DESC
         ) AS PrevCount
  FROM cte t1
 ) t1
GROUP BY LineID, Hour, Product
ORDER BY LineID, Hour, Product
```

Many thanks

Comment: I can't work out what is happening in the 3rd-7th rows of your data. 2nd row = +3A, 3rd = +72A, then what?

Comment: Ok, machine can run two products at the same time, but only one of this products is outputting. So in row 4 product B already started but is not outputting yet. On row 5 product A is ended, and on row 6-7 product B start outputting. The data for product B should start counting from 6 (which should be read as 0 for product B).

Comment: The `2014-01-28 07:58:02.000` entry has the count of 332 and `2014-01-28 07:57:06.000` is 364? Is it possible or was there a typo there?

Comment: Also, is the 78 in your desired output for Line 1 Product B Hour 7 supposed to reflect the data sample or is that a random number? I'd expect it to be 68 assuming 389 was the last count for Line 1 Hour 7.

Comment: @Andriy M, I have updated the table as it was a typo. I have also add some more data top the table. The other table is just a random values.

Answer (score 1):

Your data is fairly horrific to report against, if you can report against data that doesn't have rows for products that aren't outputting, or even better where the `HourCount` is not incremental it'll be a whole lot easier to work with.

First off I chose to build a CTE that calculated for each row, whether or not the row corresponded to a product that was outputting.

```
SELECT t1.*
  ,CASE WHEN t1.Product <> 
            (SELECT top 1 Product
             FROM t t2
             WHERE t2.TimeStamp < t1.TimeStamp
               AND t1.Line = t2.Line
             ORDER BY TimeStamp desc
                     ,CASE WHEN t1.Product = t2.Product
                           THEN 1
                           ELSE 0
                      END DESC
             ) 
        THEN 0
        ELSE 1
   END AS InProduction
FROM t t1
```

Then I get the difference in `HourCount` between each row, `0`ing the value if the product wasn't outputting in its previous row. Then I `GROUP` those values.

```
SELECT Line
    ,Product
    ,Hour
    ,SUM(CASE WHEN PrevInProduction = 1 
              THEN HourCount - PrevCount
              ELSE 0
         END) AS Units
FROM (SELECT t1.*
            ,(SELECT top 1 InProduction
              FROM cte t2
              WHERE t2.TimeStamp < t1.TimeStamp
                AND t1.Product = t2.Product
                AND t1.Line = t2.Line
              ORDER BY TimeStamp DESC
             ) AS PrevInProduction
            ,(SELECT top 1 HourCount
              FROM cte t2
              WHERE t2.TimeStamp < t1.TimeStamp
                AND t1.Product = t2.Product
                AND t1.Line = t2.Line
              ORDER BY TimeStamp DESC
             ) AS PrevCount
      FROM cte t1
     ) t1
GROUP BY Line, Hour, Product
ORDER BY Line, Hour, Product
```

It certainly looks like it can be optimised, but it gives the expected result for your given test data on [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/49f18/57/0)

Comment: I have tried this but is not giving my right results. When I add this row (1, 'A', 7, '2014-01-28 07:58:02.000', 332) to your SQLFiddle between row 6 and 7 I will get wrong results. The product change usually takes about 5-10 rows. Other then that it works well. I will have a play and will try to redesign this. Thanks

Comment: @Whistler, If you add that row I'm unclear on how you can know which product is outputting

Comment: Ok, when you see that product A and B have the same HourCount it means that the previous one which been running is the current outputting (A in this example). Then if only B is showing with the increased HourCount than means A is finished and B started outputting. hope that make sens

Comment: I found that I can add to the table exact time at which product stops outputting. Unfortunately no date is stored when is starting to outputting. Would that be helpful?

Comment: Sorry man, I came up with a solution for the data provided but I can't think of how to solve it any further. If you can work out a decent way of deciding if a product is outputting in the cte then the second query will do the rest of it.

Comment: I have just updated the question, have added new column to the data, which displays when each product was ended. I have slightly edited your solution and it gives me almost exact values, except of if machine is still running. Many thanks for your help. I have learn really a lot from your code

Comment: No problem, when I have some time I'll come have another play around but honestly I'm fairly stumped

Answer (score 0):

Really hard to understand what you're trying to do here. But if it's just about finding the number of products per line per hour, you can just do this:

```
-- Uncomment the #1 sections if you want dates too
SELECT Line, Product, Hour, COUNT(*) AS ProductCountPerHour 
   --, CAST(TimeStamp as DATE) DateVal /* #1 */
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY Line, Product, Hour 
   --, CAST(TimeStamp as DATE) DateVal /* #1 */
ORDER BY -- DateVal ASC, /* #1 */
   Hour ASC
```

Scratch Line from the SELECT and GROUP BY, and you'll get the number of all products across all the lines, per hour

Comment: Sorry, I should be more specific. Will update the question in few minutes. Thanks

Comment: `COUNT(*)` is only going to count the number of records, which has nothing to do with the number of products.

Comment: This is why I said it's hard to understand. Now thanks to the edit explaining that HourCount is actually productCount per machine, this is doable. :) But I'm assuming your reply below will work, will check in on this later.